# How do I solve a differential equation numerically after numerical integration over a part?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerical-value

Suppose I have the following function
`yteq[z_] := NIntegrate[f //. params //. {x -> z}, {y, 1, 100}]`
where `f//. params` is dependent on x and y such that it is impossible to integrate analytically.
I now need to to solve the ordinary differential equation `ODE = yt'[z] + z^(-2)*(yt[z]^2 - yteq[z]^2) == 0` numerically, but if I try
`sol = NDSolve[{ODE, yt[1] == yteq[1]}, yt, {z, 1, 100}]`
I get the error message, that the integrand `f //. params` has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region (1,100). I suppose that it has something to do with the order, Mathematica calculates the different steps involved, but I haven't come up with a solution, yet.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
f[x_, y_] := a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + y
params = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4};
yteq[z_] := NIntegrate[f[x, y] //. params /. {x -> z}, {y, 1, 10}]
ODE = yt'[z] + z^(-2)*(yt[z]^2 - yteq[z]^2) == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{ODE, yt[1] == yteq[1]}, yt[z], {z, 1, 100}]
```

Comment: Look at what `f //. params` for given parameters and x, y returns.

Comment: It returns a number, if I fix x and y. The //.params fixes all other variables the function f has except x and y.

Comment: Try: ` NIntegrate[ Evaluate[ f //. params //. {x -> z}], {y, 1, 100}]

Comment: I did try that didn't work. I'll make a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that `yteq` is only called with numeric arguments.

```
Clear[yteq];
f[x_, y_] := a x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + y
params = {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3, d -> 4};
yteq[z_ /; NumericQ[z]] := 
 NIntegrate[f[x, y] //. params /. {x -> z}, {y, 1, 10}]
ODE = yt'[z] + z^(-2)*(yt[z]^2 - yteq[z]^2) == 0;
sol = NDSolve[{ODE, yt[1] == yteq[1]}, yt[z], {z, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks!